# Yii page not redirect

Tags: redirect, yii

I have 2 forms

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'step1-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>false,
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        'validateOnChange'=>false,

),
```

in Controller

```
if(isset($_POST['yt0']))
{
    Yii::app()->request->cookies['step'] = new CHttpCookie('step', '1');
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl("timeshares/edit"));  
}
```

in GET i have html code new page but in screen i have old page 
pic http://rghost.ru/46015416.view

Comment: redirect uses full URL (http://) or an array to an action/id. Refer to the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['model_name']))
{
    Yii::app()->request->cookies['step'] = new CHttpCookie('step', '1');
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl("timeshares/edit"));  
}
```

Instead `model_name` insert your model name. if your model name is `yt0` then is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->redirect(array('timeshares/edit'));
```

But I was wondering, `edit` might need ID. If yes, then try this:

```
$this->redirect(array('timeshares/edit','id'=>$user));
```